# Beamer footline problem

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I notice that in the footline of all the slides of my thesis (above the two blue lines) a white writing appears (which seems to be my name) as if there was an additional footline that I hadn't noticed.

I notice it because it overlaps with some images.
How can I take it off?

I enclose the code and the photo investigated.

Thank you!!!

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx} %font Times New Roman

\newcommand{\pngfigspath}{./figures_png_beamer/} %cartella delle immagini
\newcommand{\jpgfigspath}{./figures_jpg_beamer/}

\title{Indagine numerica sulle prestazioni di una turbina eolica ad asse verticale di tipo troposchiano}
\author{\texorpdfstring{\large Alessandro Donadeo\\ \vspace{0.2cm} \small Relatore: Chiar.mo Prof. Marco Savini\\ \small Correlatore: Dott.ssa Nicoletta Franchina}{Alessandro Donadeo}}
\date{\small{Tesi di Laurea Magistrale, 25 settembre 2020}}
%\logo{\includegraphics[width=15mm]{\pngfigspath Unibg}}
\institute[Università degli studi di Bergamo]{Corso di Laurea Magistrale in Ingegneria meccanica\\Università degli studi di Bergamo}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %sopprime menù navigazione

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{} %sopprime testata e piè di pagina
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\begin{frame}
    \vspace{-0.5cm}
    \maketitle
    \centering
    \vspace{-0.3cm}
    \includegraphics[width=15mm]{\pngfigspath Unibg}
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}[miniframes theme] %ripristina testata e piè pagina
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[miniframes theme]

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Indice}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Introduzione}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Introduzione - alcuni dati}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \textbf{Italia}\\
            $10\,GW$ capacità installati.
            $5,3\,\%$ produzione en. elettrica.
            
            \begin{flushright}
            \textbf{Europa}\\
            Energia elettrica dal vento:\\
            $DK$ $40\,\%$, $IRL$ $25\,\%$,\\
            $GER$, $E$, $UK$ $15\,\%$.
            \end{flushright}
            
            \textbf{Mondo}\\
            $600\,GW$ capacità installati.\\
            $5,5\,\%$ produzione en. elettrica.
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{Energia eolica}
                Energia del vento, cioè l'energia cinetica di una massa d'aria in movimento.
            \end{block} 
        Rinnovabile, alternativa e pulita.\\
        Conversione in energia meccanica ed elettrica.
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Introduzione - le turbine eoliche}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\jpgfigspath sandia}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{VAWT}
                \textit{Vertical Axis Wind Turbine}.\\
            \end{block} 
        Vantaggi rispetto a HAWT:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item orientazione al vento;
            \item distribuzione dei pesi;
            \item semplicità produttiva;
            \item installazione e manutenzione.
        \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Introduzione - il tipo troposchiano}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath Quote}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{Troposchiana}
                Curva che assume una fune ideale (trasmette solo sforzi di trazione) assumendo che sia ancorata agli estremi ed in rotazione lungo la linea che li connette.
            \end{block} 
        Trascurando la gravità, la forma dipende solo dalla lunghezza della fune e dalla distanza degli estremi.
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{Modello geometrico}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Modello geometrico - il profilo NACA 0021}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath 0021}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{Profilo palare}
                Interpolazione lineare con spaziatura "mezzo coseno".
            \end{block} 
        Infittimento variabile, più raffinato verso bordo d'attacco e uscita.
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Modello geometrico - la pala}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\jpgfigspath Hr}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{Sviluppo palare}
                Interpolazione spline cubica.
            \end{block} 
        Infittimento fisso, continuità $C^{1}$ ed estremi vincolati.
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Modello geometrico - il prototipo}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\jpgfigspath ISO}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{Struttura 3D}
                Posizionamento profili, estrusioni e parti accessorie.
            \end{block} 
        Profili equidistanziati di $120\,^\circ$ (azimuth);
        palo e sostegni meccanici troncoconici d'estremità.
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Modello geometrico - una variante}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.63\columnwidth]{\jpgfigspath Attacco}\\
            \includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{\jpgfigspath Attacco parallelo}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{Struttura 3D-bis }
                Variazione modalità di estrusione curvilinea del profilo.
            \end{block} 
            Profilo sempre parallelo al piano equatoriale.
            Tangenza profili/sostegni.
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{Modello fluidodinamico}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Modello fluidodinamico - il dominio}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\jpgfigspath 3DRegioni}\\
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\jpgfigspath 3DGeometriaSezione}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{Dominio di calcolo}
                Regione di simulazione fluidodinamica attorno alla turbina.
            \end{block} 
            Definizione regioni fisse e rotanti, condizioni iniziali ed al contorno, interfacce.
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Modello fluidodinamico - le traverse}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\jpgfigspath 3DTraverse}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{Traverse di misura}
                Luoghi geometrici di acquisizione dati in scia al rotore.
            \end{block} 
        Caso 3D: due superfici, curva e piatta.\\
        Caso 2D: una linea. 
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Modello fluidodinamico - i controlli}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.75\columnwidth]{\jpgfigspath Offset}\\
            \includegraphics[width=0.75\columnwidth]{\jpgfigspath TE}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{Griglia: elementi di controllo}
                Imposizione locale della taglia delle celle.
            \end{block} 
            Volumi di controllo;
            Superfici di controllo;
            Curve di controllo.
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Modello fluidodinamico - la griglia 2D}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\jpgfigspath 2DMeshLontano}\\
            Dominio, vista dall'alto
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\jpgfigspath 2DMeshVicinissimo}\\
            Profilo, bordo d'uscita 
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Modello fluidodinamico - la griglia 3D}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\jpgfigspath 3DMeshSezione}\\
            Dominio, sezione
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\jpgfigspath 3DMeshPala}\\
            Pala, dettaglio dell'intorno
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{Risultati}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Risultati 2D - campo di moto TSR 4,0 ($\theta =90\,^\circ$)}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR4_Tu_Theta90}\\
            Intensità di turbolenza $Tu\%$
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR4_V_adim_Theta90}\\
            Velocità adimensionale~$\frac{V}{V_{\infty}}$
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR4_Vort_adim_Theta90}\\
            Vorticità adimensionale~$\frac{\omega c}{V_{\infty}}$
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Risultati 2D - coppia e scia TSR 4,0}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR4_ZH1_grafico coppia}\\
            Cefficiente di momento $C_{M}$
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR4_ZH1_Tu}\\
            Intensità di turbolenza $Tu\%$
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR4_ZH1_V_adim}\\
            Velocità adimensionale~$\frac{V}{V_{\infty}}$
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Risultati 2D - campo di moto TSR 3,1 ($\theta =90\,^\circ$)}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR3.1_Tu_Theta90}\\
            Intensità di turbolenza $Tu\%$
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR3.1_V_adim_Theta90}\\
            Velocità adimensionale~$\frac{V}{V_{\infty}}$
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR3.1_Vort_adim_Theta90}\\
            Vorticità adimensionale~$\frac{\omega c}{V_{\infty}}$
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Risultati 2D - coppia e scia TSR 3,1}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR3.1_ZH1_grafico coppia}\\
            Cefficiente di momento $C_{M}$
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR3.1_ZH1_Tu}\\
            Intensità di turbolenza $Tu\%$
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR3.1_ZH1_V_adim}\\
            Velocità adimensionale~$\frac{V}{V_{\infty}}$
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Risultati 2D - campo di moto TSR 2,4 ($\theta =90\,^\circ$)}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR2.4_Tu_Theta90}\\
            Intensità di turbolenza $Tu\%$
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR2.4_V_adim_Theta90}\\
            Velocità adimensionale~$\frac{V}{V_{\infty}}$
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR2.4_Vort_adim_Theta90}\\
            Vorticità adimensionale~$\frac{\omega c}{V_{\infty}}$
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Risultati 2D - coppia e scia TSR 2,4}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR2.4_ZH1_grafico coppia}\\
            Cefficiente di momento $C_{M}$
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR2.4_ZH1_Tu}\\
            Intensità di turbolenza $Tu\%$
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR2.4_ZH1_V_adim}\\
            Velocità adimensionale~$\frac{V}{V_{\infty}}$
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Risultati 2D - campo di moto TSR 2,0 ($\theta =90\,^\circ$)}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR2_Tu_Theta90}\\
            Intensità di turbolenza $Tu\%$
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR2_V_adim_Theta90}\\
            Velocità adimensionale~$\frac{V}{V_{\infty}}$
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR2_Vort_adim_Theta90}\\
            Vorticità adimensionale~$\frac{\omega c}{V_{\infty}}$
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Risultati 2D - coppia e scia TSR 2,0}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR2_ZH1_grafico coppia}\\
            Cefficiente di momento $C_{M}$
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR2_ZH1_Tu}\\
            Intensità di turbolenza $Tu\%$
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR2_ZH1_V_adim}\\
            Velocità adimensionale~$\frac{V}{V_{\infty}}$
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Risultati 3D - campo di moto TSR 4,0 ($\theta =90\,^\circ$)}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR4(3D)_Tu_Theta90}\\
            Intensità di turbolenza $Tu\%$
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR4(3D)_V_adim_Theta90}\\
            Velocità adimensionale~$\frac{V}{V_{\infty}}$
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR4(3D)_Vort_adim_Theta90}\\
            Vorticità adimensionale~$\frac{\omega c}{V_{\infty}}$
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Risultati 3D - coppia e scia TSR 4,0}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR4(3D)_ZH1_grafico coppia_spostato a dx}\\
            Cefficiente di momento $C_{M}$
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR4(3D)_ZH1_Tu}\\
            Intensità di turbolenza $Tu\%$
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR4(3D)_ZH1_V_adim}\\
            Velocità adimensionale $\frac{V}{V_{\infty}}$
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Risultati 3D - campo di moto TSR 4,0 ($\theta =90\,^\circ$)}
    \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath sketchXconstPlanes}\\
            \vspace{0.2cm}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath sketchZconstPlanes}\\
            Piani di misura
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR4(3D)_Z3_Tu}\\
            \vspace{0.2cm}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR4(3D)_Z6_Tu}\\
            Intensità di turbolenza $Tu\%$ (piani Z3 e Z6)
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR4(3D)_X4_Vort_adim}\\
            \vspace{0.2cm}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath TSR4(3D)_Z6_Vort_adim}\\
            Vorticità adimensionale $\frac{\omega c}{V_{\infty}}$ (piani X4 e Z6)
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Risultati - prestazioni}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{\pngfigspath Cp_TSR_tropo_grafico}\\
            Coeff. di potenza $C_{P}$ in funzione di TSR equatoriale
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{Bassi TSR}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item $\Uparrow$ energ. cinetica $\Uparrow$ $C_{P}$;
                    \item $\Uparrow$ instazionarietà $\Downarrow$ $C_{P}$;
                    \item $\Uparrow$ distacco s.l. $\Downarrow$ $C_{P}$.
                \end{itemize}
            \end{block} 
            \begin{block}{Alti TSR}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item $\Downarrow$ energ. cinetica $\Downarrow$ $C_{P}$;
                    \item $\Downarrow$ instazionarietà $\Uparrow$ $C_{P}$;
                    \item $\Downarrow$ distacco s.l. $\Uparrow$ $C_{P}$.
                \end{itemize}
            \end{block} 
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{Conclusioni}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Conclusioni}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Aerodinamica complessa;
        \item comportamento puramente tridimensionale;
        \item ciclicità ed instazionarietà a regime;
        \item dipendenza dal \textit{Tip Speed Ratio};
        \item dipendenza dalla griglia di calcolo;
        \item validazione sperimentale dei risultati;
        \item individuazione strutture turbolente e vorticose.
    \end{itemize}
    
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{} %sopprime testata e piè di pagina
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\begin{frame}
    \centering
    \Large{\textbf{Grazie per l'attenzione}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The footline of the miniframes themes normally contains the author name. Because there is so much manual formatting and spacing going on in your author name, it gets pushed so high that it is no longer within the footline. To avoid this problem you could:

1. redefine the title page to take all these formatting and spacing there instead of messing with the `\author` macro. This would also result in meaningful pdf meta data.
2. or you could provide an alternative short version for the author which will be shown in the footline:

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,demo]{beamer}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx} %font Times New Roman

\newcommand{\pngfigspath}{./figures_png_beamer/} %cartella delle immagini
\newcommand{\jpgfigspath}{./figures_jpg_beamer/}

\title{Indagine numerica sulle prestazioni di una turbina eolica ad asse verticale di tipo troposchiano}
\author[Università degli studi di Bergamo]{\texorpdfstring{\large Alessandro Donadeo\\ \vspace{0.2cm} \small Relatore: Chiar.mo Prof. Marco Savini\\ \small Correlatore: Dott.ssa Nicoletta Franchina}{Alessandro Donadeo}}
\date{\small{Tesi di Laurea Magistrale, 25 settembre 2020}}
%\logo{\includegraphics[width=15mm]{\pngfigspath Unibg}}
\institute[]{Corso di Laurea Magistrale in Ingegneria meccanica\\Università degli studi di Bergamo}
\usetheme{Berlin}


\begin{document}


\setbeamertemplate{footline}[miniframes theme]

\begin{frame}
est
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```